# Filtering multiple dates and then merge specific dates together

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have to filter dates for the working days of the month: "January 2020" and then I have to find the mean value of the working days.

```
 var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2')
    .select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
    .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-03');
```

How can I make the code for this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 5, 'day_of_week')` to only include Monday to Friday. To calculate mean, you simply call `mean()` on the collection

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5bf9ec3c33a9fa557b7d5ba8dc0e74bf

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point([0, 10]).buffer(1000)
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-02-01') // Only January 2020
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 5, 'day_of_week')) // Only workdays

var mean = collection
  .mean()
  .clip(aoi)
  
Map.addLayer(mean, {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', min: 500, max: 3000})
Map.centerObject(mean)
```